# How to get orthogonal rank-$1$ approximations?

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, matrix-rank, rank-1-matrices

Given $k$ matrices $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k \in {\Bbb R}^{m \times n}$, I would like to find the matrices $\tilde{A}_1, \tilde{A}_2, \dots, \tilde{A}_k$ such that

1. $\tilde{A}_i$ is a rank-$1$ approximation of $A_i$
2. trace zero orthogonal to all matrices $\tilde{A}_j$ with $i > j$, thus
   $$\operatorname{Tr} \bigl( \tilde{A}_i \tilde{A}_j^\top \bigr) = 0$$

For $k=2$ this is not a problem, but does anybody have an idea how to proceed when, e.g., $k=8$?

Comment: what do you mean by rank 1 **approximation**?

Comment: sorry not having specified this: with $\tilde{A}_i$ being a rank 1 approximation of $A_i$ I mean $\tilde{A}_i$ is of rank 1 and approximates $A_i$ as good as possible in terms of a small relative norm difference ($\frac{|| \tilde{A}_i - A_i || }{|| A_i ||}$) being small - like the matrix $A'_i=\sigma_1 \vec{u}_{1} \vec{v}_1^{\top}$ (with [u $\sigma$ v]=svd($A_i$) ) is a rank 1 approximation of $A_i$.

Comment: do you need a numerical method or an analytical solution? the later one would be difficult

Comment: A numerical method/procedure is all I hope for - if you have an idea, this would be great

Comment: In the definition for rank 1 approximation, what norm do you use ? The Frobenius norm ?